# Sybase STR function changes zeroes to nines

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm converting the contents of a numeric column to text.  The column's properties are `NUMERIC(29,14)`.  This is the SELECT statement I am running

```
SELECT TRIM(STR(<my_column>, 44, 14)) 
FROM <my_table>;
```

The conversion to String is transforming the trailing zeroes to nines.  So that 295.737462 is being converted to a String '295.73746199999999' when it should be '295.73746200000000'.

What is happening here?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Hans, [that link answered my question](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

I was also able to get around the issue by simply using `CAST(<my_column> AS VARCHAR)`